# Anonymous Gists expiration/lifetime?

Tags: github, github-api, gist

I'd like to know if anonymous github gists expire

I can't find anything on [Github's gist API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) and google yield results on how to delete them but nothing on their expiration (if any)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

⚠️ As of [March 19, 2018, anonymous gist creation is deprecated](https://github.blog/2018-02-18-deprecation-notice-removing-anonymous-gist-creation/). ⚠️

---

No, they don't expire. The [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists/#creating-an-anonymous-gist) says:

> **Warning**: Anonymous gists cannot be deleted from the web. To have an anonymous gist deleted, contact GitHub support. Please provide the URL of the gist you wish to delete.

You still have the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button as long you have the session on Gist, but once you delete your cookies, that delete button will be gone and if you want to delete the gist you created, you will have to [contact GitHub Support](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-anonymous-gist/).

> If you need an anonymous gist deleted, please contact [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact) and include the gist's URL.

So, summarizing, you can delete the anonymous gists you create as long you have the session in the browser. Once you lose it, nobody will delete them unless GitHub support really wants to. In fact they don't expire, but they can be deleted by a human if that's needed (like user gists).

---

To make sure, I emailed support and they said:

> You're correct. Anonymous Gists don't expire, and are not automatically deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did want documentation excerpts, but those you included aren't related to expiration nor says anything about it. "Anonymous gists cannot be deleted from the web" just mean you cannot delete them from the _web_ as in the site GUI

Comment: @JSelser See my edit. GitHub support said the same thing: *You're correct. Anonymous Gists don't expire, and are not automatically deleted.*

Comment: @Ionică Bizău _as long you have the session in the browser._! Are you sure ? I don't think it's linked to the session, if you open the gist in incognito or another browser, the delete button is still there! I think it's maybe linked to the IP or a duration, I haven't tested either!

Comment: @BaSsGaz yes, this is linked to your IP. just checked: created the gist, changed IP => no delete button, return the IP back - so is the delete button

Comment: It is not linked to your IP or at least IP is not the only factor. I have a gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c6a987d48174fec7c9b073935d22811 which within 30 ~ 40 minutes the 'delete' button was there and was gone later. Tested in normal window and incognito window.

Comment: Apparently, GitHub removed the capability to post anonymous gists: https://github.blog/2018-02-18-deprecation-notice-removing-anonymous-gist-creation/

Comment: RIP Gists, will be missed. thx for the heads up